# SwiftUI Inspector panel has no options (except padding)

Tags: xcode, swiftui

After command+clicking a VStack and clicking Show SwiftUI Inspector, I get this panel:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which is Xcode version?

Comment: Xcode 11.3.1 on macOS Catalina 10.15.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same issue and resolved it after upgrading my Xcode version to 11.5.

HTH.